# Why compileSdkVersion is wrong when integrating React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

While integrating React Native into an existing Android project, we get the following error when we try to sync the project:

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-restart'.
> Unsupported value: 28. Format must be one of:
>
> - android-31
> - android-31-ext2
> - android-T
> - vendorName:addonName:31

The error is thrown by `node_modules/react-native-restart/android/build.gradle`, on this line:

```
compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion')
```

In the Android project `build.gradle` we have:

```
compileSdkVersion 31
minSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 31
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is defined in a package level here https://github.com/avishayil/react-native-restart/blob/master/android/gradle.properties

```js
compileSdkVersion=28
minSdkVersion=16
targetSdkVersion=28
```

You can change it in your node_modules and save changes using patch-package

https://github.com/ds300/patch-package